# Academic, Associate or College degree?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am currently trying to find the right way to say in english that I have a degree in graphic design. In France, this two years degree happens after high school and is called **BTS** (Brevet de technicien supérieur > Advanced technician degree).

I need to be very brief, and "Diploma of Higher Education in graphic design" is too long.

I want to know which of these is more accurate :

1. Academic degree in graphic design
2. Associate degree in graphic design
3. College degree in graphic design
4. Degree in graphic design

Comment: Which country is this in relation to? The appropriate answer may be different when speaking in the UK to in America for example

Comment: @ededededed87 If I could reach both that would be great, or at least know what is best for each country and decide after

Comment: As noted, every country's education system is slightly different, and this is not so much a question of language or translation as it is of career counseling and academic bureaucracy. Particularly for an advanced country like France, there are likely to be conventional equivalencies, which your institution or the government should be able to provide. See e.g. [Reconnaissance des diplômes universitaires](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/education/university/recognition/index_fr.htm) for the EU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from a UK point of view:

Is there a reason you can't use the French name? Using a different phrase may be misleading as it may refer to a specific course that you have not done.

If you need the equivalent level in UK qualifications:

From Wikipedia: "The BTS is a level III diploma in the French diploma system (equivalent to level 5 in England, Wales and Northern Ireland)."

From the [UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/what-different-qualification-levels-mean/list-of-qualification-levels):
Level 5 qualifications are:

diploma of higher education (DipHE)
foundation degree
higher national diploma (HND)
level 5 award
level 5 certificate
level 5 diploma
level 5 NVQ

I would avoid the top 3 as they are specific courses offered by certain universities/colleges.

I think the best option would be to call it a level 5 qualification/diploma. Or call it a BTS and mention that it is equivalent to a level 5 qualification if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually, I don't need to be precise, the most important thing is the "design graphic" part, I don't need to give the exact diploma. I just didn't know how to say that I have a graphic design degree without being too precise. Would it be understadable if I just say "I studied graphic design" ?

Comment: Yes although this is quite vague so you risk underselling yourself as you don't specify how long for or to what level. It is not clear whether you have done 1 month of school level studying or 2 years of degree level for example. If this is not an issue then saying "I studied graphic design" is fine. You could say "I studied graphic design for 2 years" if you wanted to be a bit more specific but not talk about the specific course.

Comment: I thought so. I think I am gonna go for "level 5 diploma in graphic design", thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem. I don't know what the equivalent phrase for America would be as the level 5 system is a UK system. Unfortunately, I know very little about American education so hopefully someone else can provide an answer for you about that

Comment: In the US a 2-year degree that comes after high school is most likely to be an associate's degree, often offered by a community or "junior" college, and frequently converted into the first two years of a 4-year BS or BA degree. But the French degree may not be exactly equivalent to that.

Comment: If I saw "BTS", my first thought would be Bangtan Sonyeondan. But someone with more familiarity with French education would probably recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

I would put the French name first and then “degree in graphic design” in parentheses after it to show it’s your translation. That way nobody can accuse you of misrepresenting yourself, and if they want to know in more detail what it means, they can just ask you during the interview.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, in the U.S. a degree that requires only two years to attain is called an Associates Degree. I agree with the others that I would put the French name as is followed by "(equivalent to an Associate's Degree)"

Answer (score 1):

"College degree" is technically correct, but the assumption will be that it was a bachelor's degree, so it's a bit misleading. The term "degree", especially when discussing a subject, is assumed to be an academic degree, so "Academic degree" is redundant. You can say "degree in graphic design" and it will generally be understood to mean a college degree. You could also say "BTS degree in graphic design"; that's technically redundant, since (I gather) the "B" stands for the French word for "degree", but it makes it clearer for English speaking audiences, and while web searches on just "BTS" will be dominated by Korean boy bands, searches on "BTS degree" should return relevant results. "Associate degree" is a little bit inaccurate if it wasn't actually an associate degree, but there's leeway when translating from another system of nomenclature. If you want to be more precise, you can say "Associate-equivalent degree". You can also say "Post-secondary degree" (secondary school is high school) or "Two-year degree". Other terms used for this type of degree are "technical", "trade", and "vocational".